# Retornar lista por WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Deseo retornar una lista por un webservice, la lista es de empleados, y deseo que retorne una serie de datos.

El problema es que no sé la lógica como funciona la interfaz y el servicio en WCF.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWSEmpleados
{





}

[DataContract]
public class Empleados
{
    public string Conomina { get; set; }
    public string Tipodocumento { get; set; }
    public string Documento { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido1 { get; set; }
    public string Apellido2 { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public string Fnacimiento { get; set; }
    public string Sueldoneto { get; set; }
    public string Descuento { get; set; }
    public string Sueldosecundario { get; set; }


}

public class CompositeType
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la interfaz tienes que poner

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWSEmpleados
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Empleados> getListEmpleados();
}
```

en el servicio seria

```
public class EmpleadoWCFservice : IWSEmpleados {
      public List<Empleado> GetListEmpleado() {
          List<Empleado> lstEmpleado = new List<Empleado>();
          return lstEmpleado; 
      }
}
```

Puedes encontrar mas información en este ejemplo siempre de stackoverflow
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497698/how-to-return-a-list-from-a-wcf-call)